# How effective is in-camera Noise Reduction (NR) on a Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, dslr, nikon-d5100

I've a Nikon D5100. How do the following in-cameara settings affect the RAW images produced by the camera?

1. Auto distortion control
2. Long exposure NR
3. High ISO NR

Or is it better to go with Adobe Camera RAW?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is in-camera high-ISO noise reduction worthwhile?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/is-in-camera-high-iso-noise-reduction-worthwhile)

Comment: Anything special in Nikon D5100 or could this question be generalized?

Comment: D5100 is my first DSLR so dont know about other model :/

Answer (score 3):

**None of those settings affect RAW images.**

They do affect JPEG images by reducing noise and details simultaneously. They do not give you the ability to print larger and which level you prefer is a matter of personal taste. At very high ISO, images look soft or noisy and eventually both.

Comment: Does the LENR on Nikon cameras not subtract the dark frame from the RAW file the way that LENR on Canon cameras do?