# Slow image review after long exposure shot

Tags: long-exposure

When I use the Bulb function for long exposure shots on my Canon 60D, I find the Image Review afterwards takes for ever to appear...  the camera displays 'busy' for nearly as long as the exposure took.  It does not seem right.  Any suggestion re settings?

Answer (score 2):

That's long exposure noise reduction taking place.

See [Is in-camera high-ISO noise reduction worthwhile?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/is-in-camera-high-iso-noise-reduction-worthwhile)

You can switch this off in the shooting menu.